# O que é um NullReferenceException e como faço para corrigir isso?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> System.NullReferenceException
>     HResult=0x80004003
>     Message=A referência de objecto não foi definida como uma instância de um objecto.
>     Source=App_Web_cyyu2ydb
>     StackTrace:
>      em ASP._Page_Views_Vacinacao_Index_cshtml.Execute() em D:\Em Desemvolvimento\Projetos AR\GestCentros\GestCentros\Views\Vacinacao\Index.cshtml:linha 35
>      em System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>      em System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>      em System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
>      em System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>      em System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
>      em System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
>      em System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
>      em System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>      em System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
>      em System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
>      em System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)

pretendo devolver o nome da criança com as vacinas já administradas. o que acontece é que não retorna nada para mim, pois se eu chamar o Id ele retorna o Id da Criança

```
 using GestCentros.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GestCentros.ViewModels
{
    public class VacinacaoIndexData
    {
       public IEnumerable<Vacinacao> Vacinacoes { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Vacina> Vacinas { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }

    }
}

public ActionResult Index(int? id, int? Idvacina)
{
    var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();

    if (user == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }    
    var viewModel = new VacinacaoIndexData();    
    viewModel.Vacinacoes = db.Vacinacao
        .Include(v => v.Vacinas)
        .Include(v => v.Crianca)
        .Where(c => c.IdCentro == user.IdCentro);  

    if (id != null)
    {
        ViewBag.IdVacinacao = id.Value;
        viewModel.Vacinas = viewModel.Vacinacoes
            .Single(i => i.IdVacinacao == id.Value).Vacinas;
    }    
    if (Idvacina == null) return View(viewModel);           
        ViewBag.IdVacina = Idvacina.Value;
        // Lazy loading
        viewModel.Enrollments = viewModel.Vacinas.Single(x => x.IdVacina == Idvacina).Enrollments;
    // Explicit loading
    Vacina selectedVacina = viewModel.Vacinas.Single(x => x.IdVacina == Idvacina);    
    db.Entry(selectedVacina).Collection(x => x.Enrollments).Load();

        foreach (var enrollment in selectedVacina.Enrollments)
        {
            db.Entry(enrollment).Reference(x => x.Centro).Load();
        }    
        viewModel.Enrollments = selectedVacina.Enrollments;            

    return View(viewModel);
}



    @model GestCentros.ViewModels.VacinacaoIndexData

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2 class="text-center">Lista de Crianças Vacinadas</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Data Vacinação</th>
        <th>Vacinas</th>
        <th>Operações</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Vacinacoes)
     {
        string selectedRow = "";
        if (item.IdVacinacao == ViewBag.IdVacinacao)
        {
            selectedRow = "success";
        }
        <tr class="@selectedRow">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Crianca.Nome)

            </td>
            <td>
                @item.DataVacina.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
            </td>
            <td>
                @{
                    foreach (var vacina in item.Vacinas)
                    {
                        @:  @vacina.Nome <br />
                    }
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
     }
</table>

@if (Model.Vacinas != null)
{
    <h3>Vacinas Ministradas na Campanha</h3>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Operações</th>
            <th>Vacina</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model.Vacinas)
        {
            var selectedRow = "";
            if (item.IdVacina == ViewBag.IdVacina)
            {
                selectedRow = "success";
            }
            <tr class="@selectedRow">
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Selecionar", "Index", new { IdVacina = item.IdVacina }, new { @class = "btn btn-sm btn-secundary" })
                    | @Html.ActionLink("Voltar a Lista", "Index", new { }, new { @class = "btn btn-sm btn-default" })
                </td>                
                <td>
                    @item.Nome
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
}

@if (Model.Enrollments != null)
{
    <h3>
        Students Enrolled in Selected Course
    </h3>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Enrollments)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Centro.Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Grade)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

Comment: Manuel, poste também a mensagem de erro completa.

Comment: `NullReferenceException` acontece quando um objeto não está instanciado e está tentando usá-lo. Veja a linha onde dá erro e veja qual objeto não foi instanciado

Comment: Manuel, print não ajuda! :) Clica no botão "copiar detalhes" e poste aqui. :)
Isso é importante até para novas perguntas. O comentário do Ricardo está perfeito, o erro é bastante simples. :)

Comment: Postei o Detalhe do erro

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: não Consegui resolver ainda

Comment: Ja Tentei mais nao consegui ver o erro

Comment: Eu tive uma experiência parecida com um exercício esses dias, no meu caso, estou temporariamente em um notebook Ubuntu, usando o Visual Code e o .NET Core, na minha situação eu tive que excluir as pasta bin e obj e refazer a build para que o erro parasse e o programa voltasse a rodar. Ele estava rodando normalmente e depois de algumas alterações parou e mesmo voltando ao estado anterior ele não rodava. No meu caso o debug apontava para um erro em uma linha vazia logo depois da chave de abertura de um método **{** e antes da primeira linha de código do método em questão.

Answer (score 1):

## **TL;DR:**

Você está tentando acessar uma variável de um objeto não instanciado.
Na linha `item.Crianca.Nome` ou o `item` é null, ou a prop `Crianca` de `item` é null.
Instanciando o que estiver não instanciado resolve o problema.

## **Explicação**

Existem dois tipos de valor para variáveis: `Tipos de valor` e `Tipos de referência`.

Um Tipo de valor armazena a variável na memória **Stack**. Exemplos de Tipo de Valor: `Int32`, `bool`, `double`.
Quando vc cria um tipo de valor, um espaço em memória é alocado para armazenar o valor e a variável guarda o valor diretamente.

Já o Tipo de referência armazena o objeto na memória **Heap** e cria na **Stack** apenas uma referência do endereço do objeto na `Heap`, mas não o objeto diretamente. Basicamente um ponteiro.
Exemplo: Um objeto gerado de uma classe

Quando criamos um objeto (`Crianca filho;`), é gerado na memória **Stack** um espaço para armazenar o endereço da instância (no caso, a variável é preenchida com o endereço, mas o local que o endereço aponta é null, pois ainda não foi criada a instância).

Ao instanciar o objeto(`filho = new Crianca();`) um espaço na memória **Heap** é alocado para guardar os dados da variável.

Se tentarmos acessar uma propriedade de um objeto ainda não instanciado, a **Stack** vai apontar para um valor que é nulo, logo, terá uma `NullReferenceException`

Links úteis:

[Value type vs Reference type](http://net-informations.com/faq/general/valuetype-referencetype.htm)

[Difference Heap vs Stack](http://net-informations.com/faq/net/stack-heap.htm)

Comment: Muito Obrigado Fera. vou dar uma olhada melhor. se voce poder me ajudar dando uma olhada no codigo, te agradecia

Answer (score 0):

Como foi dito nos comentários, a exception `NullReferenceException` ocorre quando acontece a tentativa de acessar um atributo ou método de um objeto não instanciado.

Iria ocorrer, por exemplo, ao tentar acessar um atributo após instanciar um objeto na forma de `Objeto instanciaObjeto;` em vez de `Objeto instanciaObjeto = new Objeto();`.

Pela imagem que foi enviada, parece que o erro ocorre ao acessar um atributo do objeto Crianca. Sugiro que verifique, com um debug, se o objeto está sendo carregado normalmente junto da Vacinacao.

Comment: Alguém Pode Ajudar no Live?

Comment: Alguém pode dar-me uma ajuda no live?